# How to increase the dialog size in touch UI, adobe cq5?

Tags: user-interface, dialog, touch, adobe, aem

i need to increase the length and breadth of the touch ui dialog, cq5. I have multpile tabs which do not fit in the small size of the dialog and hence the alignment is ruined.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "width" parameter to the _cq_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
      xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      jcr:title="My title"
      width="{Long}650"
      sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a node in your component of type cq:EditConfig and name cq:editConfig, this should be a sibling of the dialog node.
2. To the cq:editConfig node add a property with name “cq:dialogMode”, type “String” and value “floating”.
3. To your dialog node, add two properties i.e. height and width of type "Long",  and value to what you want the size of the dialog to be. That's it.

Comment: Is it `cq:height` and `cq:width`? Or just `height` and `width`?

Comment: Just height and width.